# Creating a sharepoint test site from a live site collection

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, site-collection

So I have a live site collection that I need to update but don't want to make changes on. What the best practise to do this?

Do I create a web app and site collection. Then do a back up of the live site collection and restore it on my newly created one?

Comment: On-Prem environment or SPO?

Comment: It is On prem sp2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create separate web application, you can clone the same site collection in the same web app you just need to create a new content Database. You just need to

- take the backup of site collection
- create new content Database
- restore the site collection using the Database name parameter and put the new db name.

  But one thing keep in mind, You to make sure following things.
- turn off the search because user will not get same documents from both site.
- Turn off the alerts so that while you doing stuff unecessory alerts not being generated
- remove the permissions. and only keep the users who want to work on it.

.

Comment: But can I do it the way I have done it?

Comment: you can do the way you have but it put more overhead on the server...new web application will eat more resources on the server...a new app pool etc....it is your live farm that's why i am little hesitant to create new web app.

Comment: Ok cool, well I have already created the web app and site collection. Would you suggest continuing how I am doing it or delete it all and do it how you suggest?

Comment: again, its depend how many web apps u have and how much users u have etc....but the numbers are very low then its ok but u should turn off search alerts etc

Comment: Thanks. So if I keep doing it the way I am doing I just need to do a restore-spsite with my new site collection and where I backed up the live site

Comment: that's correct.